# Python Selenium JS

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Возвращаясь в [предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1523490/python-selenium-js-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) про Selenium и Python. Вопрос решился скролингом страницы

```py
for p in range(0, 1080, 50):
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + {p})")
    time.sleep(random.choice([1, 2]))
```

Однако, там выплывает окно, которое надо закрыть, закрываешь, скролишь - данные скачиваются, нет  - нет (
PS. про API понял, тут вопрос про возможности Selenium.
PPS. сильно не ругайтесь, я новенький.

[image: Всплывающее окно]

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать такой трюк, он удаляет ненужный элемент со страницы.
`document.(тут class, id, name, text)` для поиска элемента на странице по указанному идентификатору. Затем мы проверяем, найден ли элемент, и если да, то удаляем его с помощью метода remove(). В конце мы возвращаем True, чтобы указать успешное выполнение операции удаления элемента.

```
def element_remove_for_js_class(self, element):
    self.driver.execute_script(f"var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('{element}');
                                while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();")
    return True

def element_remove_for_js_class(self, element):
    self.driver.execute_script(f"var element = document.getElementById('{element}');
                                if (element) element.remove();")
    return True
```